# Retrieve joined table results from HQL without looping

Tags: java, hql

I'm trying to retrieve joined tables result from database and my current code is like this.

Query

```
SELECT a.Name,a.employeeNo,b.status,b.amount FROM Tbemployee a left join Tbtransact b on a.employeeno = b.employeeno WHERE b.status = '7'
```

Code

```
DBService dbsrvc = DBServiceImpl();
List<EmployeeForm> formList = new ArrayList<EmployeeForm>();
List<Object[]> list = dbsrvc.executeListSQLQuery(query, params);
for(Object[] row: list){
    EmployeeForm form = new EmployeeForm();
    form.setEmpno(row[0]);
    form.setName(row[1]);
    form.setStatus(row[2]);
    form.setAmount(row[3]);
    formList.add(form);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Like retrieve the list straight to the EmployeeForm?

This is my DBService method

```
public List executeListSQLQuery(String sQuery, Map parameters) {
    // ---
    EMPLOYEEDB service = (EMPLOYEEDB) RuntimeAccess.getInstance().getServiceBean(
            DBNAME);

    try {
        service.begin();
        Session session = service.getDataServiceManager().getSession();

        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sQuery);
        query.setProperties(parameters);
        List list = query.list();
        service.commit();

        // ---
        return list;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.warn("Error executing query", ex);
        service.rollback();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: DBServiceImpl is something you have coded yourself? You tagget question as hql but seems more like sql ?

Comment: Hi sir please see my edit. I've added my executeListSQLQuery

Comment: So you are using Hibernate but using native SQL for some reason? Could you just use directly hibernate for ORM here to make things easier? Native SQL could be more performant if used propebly tough. see for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm how directly map native SQL results to entity in Hibernate

Comment: Thank you entity is the one I am looking for.